# Installing wxPython with pip (Python2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm trying to install wx python from MacOS Terminal, having tried the following 2 approaches:

> python -m pip install wxPython (also tried "...-U wxPython")
>
> sudo -H pip install wxPython

I get the following error both times:

> Collecting wxPython Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/wx/:
> There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL:
> TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version
> (_ssl.c:590) - skipping
>
> **Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wxPython (from
> versions: ) No matching distribution found for wxPython**

Using Python 2.7. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `pip install -U wxPython` from here: https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html

Comment: This yields the same error. I forgot to mention that I tried this too. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name you need to use is `wxPython` not `wx`. (https://pypi.org/project/wxPython/)

Also, you can avoid the SSL errors by updating your Python and pip to the newest versions.

Comment: 'wxPython' yields the same error. I forgot to mention that I tried this too.

Comment: Ok, so I upgraded to the newest version of 2.7 and pip. Problem solved. Thanks for answering this newbie question!

Answer (score -2):

This command worked for me:

```
pip install wxPython --user
```

Comment: Avoid posting answers like these or else add a meaningful description as to why your answer is more relevant and useful to the question.